# Calculating moles of Hydrogen gas in multiple gas container

Tags: hydrogen, combustion

If there was a 500 mL container filled with oxygen and hydrogen so it burns completely (2H:1O), how many moles of hydrogen gas would there be if there if pressure is 101.3 kPa and the temperature is 293 K?

Comment: $PV = nRT$ is your friend in this case.

Comment: I know this would work if it was pure hydrogen, but what about mixed with oxygen?

Comment: Calculate total moles of both gases with the equation and divide those moles between gases in mole ratio (2:1) that you have given in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pv = nrt$$1atm\times(0.5L) = (total moles)(.08206\frac{atm\cdot L}{mol\cdot k})(293K) \\ \text{total moles} = .02079mol $$ There are 3 total moles of gas with 2 of those being hydrogen and 1 being oxygen. This means 66% of the total moles is hydrogen and 33% is oxygen. Soooooo 66% times .02079 is the amount of hydrogen moles and 33% times .02079 is the amount of oxygen. TADA!